# Size of Boolean and Number types in Lua?

Tags: lua

How big these two types of data in Lua 5.3?

As I understand, the size varies depending on the implementation of the language and how configured compliant, and on what system is running.

Would it be faster and less costly to use `true` and `false` values for object state on, off instead of 1 and 0?

Comment: Numbers and Booleans are both 16 bytes in vanilla Lua.  You can create array of 16 million (2^24) boolean values and check the RAM amount Lua has consumed.

Comment: Boolean comparison `if x then` has (almost) the same speed as numerical comparison `if x==1 then` in Lua 5.3+

Comment: I think the part asking about execution speed should be asked as a separate question.